# Is there a website that lists for a set of at least 1000 journals OpenAccess fees for publishing an article?

Tags: publications, open-access, medicine, fees

Many journals now are open access only and every article published (authors) must pay a fee.

Sometimes, this info can be hard to find. The journals does not put it visibly on the front page (next to impact factor).

If I want to compare 80 journals in the medical field and their charges - it is not easy.

Is there a site that would 'monitor' this and have data on many journals. (any list with 50+ journals and prices listed will be a good answer) (even if domain specific) (medicine domain is preferred)

Comment: Most medical journals may be operating under a few publishers and it may be less difficult than you think. Here is a [list](http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/scholarlycommunication/oa_fees.html) that may provide some starting materials.

Comment: I would submit to whatever journal is the best fit for my paper. I don't know how to find the prices up front. But getting published is very important so if you can save up the money, publish your research.

Answer (score 3):

There is no comprehensive list.

Some partial lists are listed below: (please update when new are found)

- http://www.lib.berkeley.edu/scholarlycommunication/oa_fees.html

Comment: If you want others to update your post, you should mark it community wiki.

Comment: what do I click to mark it community wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Try [the Sherpa/RoMEO list](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/), which is the most definitive list of open access journals that I know of.  It covers many different fields.

I don't know why you are set on 1000 journals.  You can only publish your paper in one journal.  What's important is not the number of journals, but finding one good journal that is a great fit for your paper.

Comment: ok. what if that journal charges $3800 (Brit. Med. Journal) fee and there are other cheaper journals. It may be nice to know that.